# How do I add collision detection between two objects in the same array?

Tags: javascript, html

I was just coding a physics engine in HTML canvas and I wanted to add boxes that were influenced by Gravity. I coded that part successfully and I made it so that each box generation takes place using a single array which contains all the box data. Then I wanted them to collide and bump into each other like objects in real life do but couldn't do it since all the boxes are in the same array. Is there any way I could code collision detection for two objects located in the same array?

Can you please give a quick example on how object collision  between two objects in the same array.

Comment: StackOverflow usually answers Specific coding Questions. When you have a specific question, add the code that does not work and an explanation. It does not provide snippets of code upon demand.